# spring-boot: auto configure transaction manager

Tags: spring, datasource, spring-boot

Seems like I am missing something: Automatically injecting a data source works, but injection of DataSourceTransactionManager fails.

Dependencies:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  // this fails
  @Autowired
  private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

  public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I expected that the DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration would take care of it, but it didn't. Any clues?

The sample up is on github: https://github.com/jangalinski/springboot-playground

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Boot is registering `PlatformTransactionManager` bean, and you're trying to inject `DataSourceTransactionManager`. If you'll change to proper class it will work out of the box:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

Comment: PlatformTransactionManager  is autoconfigurable in Spring boot? As we need to create bean in Spring  framework.